# Facebook Server-side Authentication with Classic ASP

Tags: facebook, asp-classic

Similar to [this closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8653616/241201) but I'll make mine more precise so hopefully there'll be an answer :)

I'm adding Facebook login button to a website that's all in classic ASP, and I'm new to the Facebook SDK/API, and https ://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication gives all its code examples in PHP. I need to pass some FB user info to server's database with some COM functions, so I'm going with server-side authentication. So far so good. Server-side auth doesn't give me the **access token** directly though it gives me a **code**, and I *mostly* understand the PHP example for how to turn that into the access token,

```
$token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
   . "client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
   . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret . "&code=" . $code;
 $response = @file_get_contents($token_url);
 $params = null;
 parse_str($response, $params);
 $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" 
   . $params['access_token'];
 $user = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));
```

I really don't know the ASP / VBScript way to do any of the above. PHP comes with so many more built-in functions than ASP like `urlencode`, `file_get_contents`, a `parse_str` that's smart enough to treat the string like query parameters, and I don't even know if I want or need anything like `json_decode` or not!

For file_get_contents I am thinking of trying something like

```
fbApiCode = Request.QueryString("code")
    if len(fbApiCode) > 0 then
        set xmlHttp = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
        appAuth = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=" & _
           Application("fbAppId") & "&redirect_uri=" & Application("fbRedirectUri") & "&client_secret=" _
           Application("fbAppSecret") & "&code=" & fbApiCode
        xmlHttp.open("GET", appAuth, false) ' or post?
        accessResponse = xmlHttp.responseText
```

Is this even close to the right approach or am I running down a rabbit hole? If I can't translate the code to the access token with mere VBScript, I'll have to grab the FB user's info (name, email, etc.) in JavaScript with `FB.getLoginStatus()` and shoot that to my server with AJAX, which I know isn't terribly secure so I want to avoid resorting to that.

Comment: What type of web app is this?  A Page tab app? A canvas app?  A standalone website?

Comment: "People still use classic ASP?" Yes.

Comment: This may help http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/94067/Classic-ASP-Integration-with-Facebook-Websites-Fea

Comment: Standalone website, with its own registration/login that I need to integrate with Facebook login. Allowing old & new users to sign in w/ Facebook is really the only Facebook API feature we plan on using. (And yeah it's a lot of legacy code; until now some of the code controlling reg/login hasn't needed any changes since 2004!)

Comment: Hey @Dee that codeproject link was really helpful -- and only just posted on 1/26/12 so it literally wasn't there when I was doing my initial research / self-training on Facebook API. Good catch! Why don't you suggest it as an Answer so you can get credit ;)

Comment: Thank you EastOf Nowhere, I did have it as an answer but the StackOverflow moderators decided it wasn't good enough for them and took it away from me :/

Comment: @bkaid, look out the window. That place is called the real world. In it people have to use old technologies like classic ASP.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but this solution may help somebody.

You'll need to request the token using the code and then request the user info with the token.

```
<script language="javascript" runat="server">
"use strict";
function getJSON(strOrObject){
    if (typeof strOrObject == "string") {
        return eval("(" + strOrObject + ")");
    }
    return strOrObject;
}
</script>
<%
fbClientToken = [[CLIENTTOKEN]]
fbAppID = [[APPID]]
fbAppSecret = [[APPSECRET]]

fbAuthURL = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth"
fbTokenURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/oauth/access_token"
fbOAuthCallback = [[CALLBACKURL]]
fbScope = "public_profile,email"
if request("go")="login" then
    Randomize
    nonce = Rnd
    response.redirect fbAuthURL & "?response_type=code&client_id=" & fbAppID & "&redirect_uri=" & Server.URLEncode(fbOAuthCallback) & "&scope=" & fbScope & "&state=" & nonce
else
    if request("code") <> "" then       
        information = "client_id=" & fbAppID & "&redirect_uri=" & Server.URLEncode(fbOAuthCallback) & "&client_secret=" & fbAppSecret & "&code=" & request("code")
        Set xmlhttp = server.Createobject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
        xmlhttp.Open "GET", fbTokenURL & "?" & information, false
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        xmlhttp.send        
        respText = xmlhttp.ResponseText     
        if InStr(respText,"access_token") then
            dim respJSON : set respJSON = getJSON(respText)
            getURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" & respJSON.access_token
            xmlhttp.Open "GET", getURL, false
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            xmlhttp.send
            respToken = xmlhttp.ResponseText
            %><h1>Token Inspection Response</h1><%
            if InStr(respToken,"{") and InStr(respToken,"}") then
                dim userJSON : set userJSON = getJSON(respToken)
                response.write "<br/>ID: " & userJSON.id
                response.write "<br/>email: " & userJSON.email
                response.write "<br/>first_name: " & userJSON.first_name
                response.write "<br/>last_name: " & userJSON.last_name
                response.write "<br/>name: " & userJSON.name
                response.write "<br/>gender: " & userJSON.gender
                response.write "<br/>locale: " & userJSON.locale
                response.write "<br/>verified: " & userJSON.verified
                response.write "<br/>link: " & userJSON.link
                response.write "<br/>timezone: " & userJSON.timezone
            else
                %><h1>Invalid Inspection Response</h1><%=respToken%><%
            end if          
        else
            %><h1>Invalid Response</h1><%=respText%><%
        end if
    end if
end if
%>
```